# ASP.NET App - Set IE7-Compatibility Mode?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8

What is the simpliest way to set the IE7-Compatibility Mode mode in an ASP.NET application to deal with IE8 issues?  Is it possible to set this via the web.config or must it either be set at the IIS or page level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the header

`X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7`

in the HTTP Headers tab of the site or application properties in IIS manager.  In IIS7 its the HTTP Response Headers feature.

You can place it the `<system.webServer>` section of a web.config

```
   <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmultateIE7" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Comment: Thanks, so this can just be added to web.config on an app by app basis as needed correct?

Comment: yes but since you can configure this at application or folder level in IIS manager I prefer to use IIS manager on IIS6 (on IIS7 its all the same).  For a pure ASP.NET app either way should be fine.

Comment: **AnthonyWJones**
but what about IE 9?
in my case this code don't work properly... :(

Comment: @vladimir: I can't think why, I use IE9 a lot and when accessing site s sending this header (and I do that a lot too) my IE9 behaves as IE7.

Answer (score 1):

If the solution posted here did not work for you, see my question and answer here [ASP.NET Ignores IE7 Compatibility Mode Tag in Web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209183/asp-net-ignores-ie7-compatibility-mode-tag-in-web-config/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use META tags to influence IE8 to set its mode accordingly:

http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2009/03/19/change-ie8-to-ie7-compatible-mode-with-meta-tags.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `value="IE=EmultateIE7"`

Replace with `value="IE=EmulateIE7"`