# ASP.NET Ignores IE7 Compatibility Mode Tag in Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have the following section in my Web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
    <!-- For now..... lets be safe and put IE8 in IE7 compatibility mode-->
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE7" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

but the

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
```

is not present in the header of the pages when they are rendered on my site. I followed the advice in this post [ASP.NET App - Set IE7-Compatibility Mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713581/asp-net-app-set-ie7-compatibility-mode) but it does not appear to be working as expected using IE8 and IIS6. Any hints?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I'm using **IIS6**. IIS6 looks at the `<system.web>` section of Web.config instead of the `<system.webServer>` section (which is used by IIS7, unless it's running in compatibility mode). To render this meta tag on every page of your site when running IIS6, I believe the best option is to add it to your MasterPage. I ended up adding the following code block to the OnPreRender event of my MasterPage:

```
Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(0, new HtmlMeta { HttpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible", Content = "IE=EmulateIE7" });
```

The reason I used AddAt instead of just plain Add is because the X-UA-Compatible meta tag apparently has to be the first thing in the page header in order for it to be respected.

Hope this helps someone in the same boat!

Comment: can't you just add it to the <head> section of the master page instead of adding it with code?

Comment: @codeulike - Yes, I think that should work fine. It's been a couple of years, and I can't remember now why I chose to add it programmatically.

Comment: If you put this in both the system.web section and the system.WebServer section, would it work in both IIS7 and IIS7 ?

Comment: @Anthony - No, [IIS6 does not support the `<customHeaders>` section](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders).