# Add http headers to Cassini via config

Tags: asp.net, cassini, http-headers

Our asp.net web site is currently deployed to an IIS7 server. We are setting some http headers via the config file such as this:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE7" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

This works great for myself as I host my personal web under IIS. My Co-Worker is pretty bent on continuing to use Cassini for his development experience, which means our custom headers are not being sent. Is there a way to tell cassini to send these headers?

I would rather not have to code up a custom module to add this, and I don't want to add the header on every page in our site.

Comment: Would it be possible to do a conditional configuration when you're in development? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209183/asp-net-ignores-ie7-compatibility-mode-tag-in-web-config/

Comment: Isn't Cassini still the "preferred" way of doing local development?

Comment: @ahsteele: I like to develop under the same version of iis we deploy too. Since Cassini is based on IIS6 I prefer to use IIS7. The configuration is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is in the todo for the next release of [CassiniDev](http://CassiniDev.codeplex.com), amongst others that may be of interest.

Comment: That looks cool...thanks. IIS Express should also be a much better option than the classic Cassini.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could add a pre-compiler directive in the Global.asax so it will only add the header when compiled in DEBUG mode:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
#if DEBUG
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=EmulateIE7");
#endif
}
```

The production RELEASE compilation would ignore this but continue to add the header via the web.config setting in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a meta tag in your master page (e.g. `Site.Master`), Casini will process that:

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```