# IIS6 Ignores IE7 Compatibility Mode Tag in Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

From; [ASP.NET Ignores IE7 Compatibility Mode Tag in Web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1209183/386165)

```
<system.web>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE7" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.web>
```

Related to the answer Chris Shouts added;

When I attempt to add the `<httpProtocols>` sections into the `<system.web>` I get

```
Parser Error Message: Unrecognized configuration section system.web/httpProtocol.
```

Any tips?
I ideally need to be able to add customHeaders through the IIS6 web.config (I however am assuming this won't work)

thanks

Comment: Read that discussion carefully. If you use IIS 6, web.config cannot achieve the goal.

Answer (score 2):

It should `<system.webServer>` instead of `<system.web>`

Comment: from the original post 'IIS6 looks at the <system.web> section of Web.config instead of the <system.webServer> section'

Comment: Wayne is right. There is no `<httpProtocol>` under `System.Web`

Answer (score 0):

Do you accidentally have 2 `<system.web>` sections in your web.config?